# Calculating max/min for every n rows of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, min

I want to calculate the min/max for every n rows of a df, say 10, but using df.rolling(10).max() gives the values for rows 0-9, 1-10, 2-11 etc. I want 0-9, 10-19, 20-29 etc

Is there a neat way of doing this for a large dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)
to calculate an array of `0` to `len (df) -1` and then calculate the entire divison. We can use this array together with [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
n=9
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//n).max()
```

---

### **Example**

**Setup**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':range(30)})
print(df)
     A
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
20  20
21  21
22  22
23  23
24  24
25  25
26  26
27  27
28  28
29  29
```

---

**Solution**

```
n=9
df_max = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//n).max()
print(df_max)
    A
0   8
1  17
2  26
3  29
```

As you can see, groups listed from 0 to m are created. The resulting DataFrame is the maximum of each group.

---

You could also select columns to calculate `max`

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//n)[cols].max()
```

and of course use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) if you want to use more than one function

**Detail**

```
np.arange(len(df))//n
#array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
#       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

**EDIT**

```
first_row = 2
df2 = df[first_row:]
df2.groupby(np.arange(len(df2))//n).max()
```

Comment: This works nicely! Is there a way to offset it so the first row can be any row?

Comment: Yes, check section EDIT

Answer (score 3):

The key to success is grouping by *np.arange(len(df.index)) // 10* (or change
*10* (the group size) to whatever other value you need).

Assuming that you have 3 columns to compute min / max (*['A', 'B', 'C']*),
you can run:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 10)[['A', 'B', 'C']].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Comment: this is my solution by changing `len(df)` to len `(df.index)` please do not copy solution

Comment: Our solutions are just 3 minutes apart, so nobody can claim that I just copied your solution. On the other hand, I included code to compute **all** required functions, not only *max()*.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from pandas 1.5.0 you can use `df.rolling(10, step=10).max()`.

From Pandas documentation:

> step: int, default None
>
> Evaluate the window at every step result, equivalent to slicing as
> [::step]. window must be an integer. Using a step argument other than
> None or 1 will produce a result with a different shape than the input.